# Best internet sites for British English learners?

Tags: resources

What are  some  great resources for advanced British English learners?

Comment: But what resources can I use?

Comment: You can start by looking for all the questions regarding British English, on this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about English. It is about finding resources on the Internet.

Comment: Essentially a *meta* question?

Answer (score 4):

You might like to try the [British Council](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/) and the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/).